# ArrowInvalid: Could not convert with type Image: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to work with Hugging Face Datasets to for a sample problem. I want to turn some random images upside down, and change the label based on it. The approach I used is the following.

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("cats_vs_dogs", ignore_verifications=True)

def upside_down(img_dict):
  """
  Randomly splits an image. if it is splitted, label is 1, else label is 0
  """
  img_dict['labels']=0 # straight by default
  num = random.randint(0,1)
  if num==1:
    try:
      img_dict['image'] = img_dict['image'].transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    except:
      img_dict['labels']=0 # if exception, image is orignal, so no need to change label
    img_dict['labels']=1 # if no exception, change label to 1

  return img_dict

dataset.map(upside_down)
```

Now when I run this, I get the following error,

```
ArrowInvalid: Could not convert <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=341x500 at 0x7F1F5C95E810> with type Image: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
```

Even if I wrap the whole function in try catch, i get this exception.

```py
def upside_down(img_dict):
  """
  Randomly splits an image. if it is splitted, label is 1, else label is 0
  """
  try:
    img_dict['labels']=0 # straight by default
    num = random.randint(0,1)
    if num==1:
      try:
        img_dict['image'] = img_dict['image'].transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
      except:
        img_dict['labels']=0 # if exception, image is orignal, so no need to change label
      img_dict['labels']=1 # if no exception, change label to 1
  except:
    return img_dict
  return img_dict
```

Error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Could not convert <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=341x500 at 0x7F1F5CB34090> with type Image: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same thing. The problem is that you need to cast the Pillow image back to the [Image feature](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.4.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Image) of the Datasets library.

```
from datasets import Image

feature = Image()
# assuming image is a Pillow image
img_dict['image'] = feature.encode_example(image)
```

Comment: kudos! this helped me a lot.